# Remove deployment key from Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys, public-key

I am having problems to add my ssh public key to my bitbucket account. It seems that i accidentally added my personal key as a deployment key for my bitbucket team. Now when I am trying to add it as my accounts key, it states that this key is already in usage. How can I delete my teams deployment key that I added accidentally? Do I have to delete the team? It seems I just cant find the option. I already have several public keys connected to my git account that are working.

I am using this tutorial, theoretically it seems pretty easy to me:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPhLLDvDW-8

I also tried this one from Bitbucket.com:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, deleting the team is unnecessary.

This page seems to have settings for your team SSH keys (fill in your team name)
https://bitbucket.org/account/user/your_team_name/ssh-keys/

You should be able to delete the key on that page.

Comment: Sorry, your solution didn't work for me. There are no keys added, whether in team settings nor for my profile.

Comment: I figured it out how to do it. Instead of adding an ssh key to my account I added the key to my teams' deploy keys. To delete the key I had to go to Teams -> my team -> Manage team -> ssh keys. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please edit the answer to include the actual solution? So it will get useful for the future.